# my apps call over and over again (tel: + phoneNumber)

Tags: java, android

My Apps need to make a call several time according to the user need.

```
public class callDelay implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int count = 0 ; count < (Integer.parseInt(myGate.getNumberOfAttempts().toString())); count++){

            try {
                Intent openGateNow = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                openGateNow.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + myGate.getGatePhoneNumber().toString()));//to call a phone number must use "tel:"+ the number
                startActivity(openGateNow);             
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(myGate.getCallDelay().toString())*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        callNowFlag = false;
        speedVerification = false;
    }       
}
```

The problem is that when i call this thread, it ignore the counter and calls over and over again without delays and with no counter limits (i have to stop it my self).

I would like it to call just X number of times and with delay between the calls.

what is wrong with my code?
what reset the counters and delay?

Comment: What does this return `myGate.getCallDelay().toString()` ?

Comment: This is a Runnable. Where's the code that's starting it?

Comment: it contain int number that should create a delay between calls, i try to insert a number instead but i have the same results.